# Why doesn't rc.local run entirely

Tags: x11, startup, init-script

Here is my rc.local

```sh
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
/bin/echo 12 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
/bin/echo disable > /proc/acpi/ibm/bluetooth

# Samsung at home
/usr/bin/xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240 1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
/usr/bin/xrandr --addmode VGA1 1680x1050_60.00
/usr/bin/xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1680x1050_60.00

exit 0
```

whose permission is `-rwxr-xr-x`.

**The first command works, I can set the brightness of my laptop's monitor.** The following script is to disable bluetooth and to set resolution of my external monitor.

Only the first command is correctly executed, not the others.

I know that rc.local stops running when a command fails. However, I've tried to run it manually

```
/bin/sh /etc/rc.local
```

Everything seems to work correctly, the bluetooth is disabled and the resolution is set without problem. I've also tried to run the first command in terminal

```
/bin/echo 12 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
echo $?
```

It shows that the first command returns zero.

So I don't understand why the system doesn't run all the commands in rc.local. I really need it, especially for the first 2 lines which need root permission.

Comment: Try putting `set -x` in the script to have debugging info printed to the screen. Or pipe each commands standard error and standard out to `tee`

Comment: Add `exec >/var/tmp/rc.local.1.out 2>/var/tmp/rc.local.2.out` at the beginning of the file and check those files for error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/etc/rc.local` is executed before the [X server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_server) starts, so it has no access to any GUI features. The `xrandr` commands cannot have any effect.

Put the `xrandr` commands in a different file, which runs when your GUI session starts. The file depends on your desktop environment.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles, I've put the xrandr commands in an other file and added it to the autostart list of my xfce environment. Now the resolution setting works.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved,

As @Gilles said, I should put xrandr commands in an other file since `rc.local` is executed before X. So I've put all xrandr commands in a other script file, and added it to the auto-start list of my xfce environment, now resolution setting works.

However for Bluetooth, apparently it's a timing issue, I've found that the Bluetooth is disabled for a few milliseconds, then turn on again. It looks like something has reactivate the Bluetooth after running `rc.local`.

So I've added `sleep 5` at the beginning of `rc.local`, now problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than loosing 5 seconds to sleep why not put the Bluetooth disable to your xrandr script that runs with auto-start?